# How to store a file reference for a PDF file in MYSQL to retrieve in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, download, uploading

I am trying to store a reference to a PDF file in MySQL, I then want to load a few files on to a webpage. When I click on the file name I would like the file to load. How do I store the reference in MySQL and access it via PHP?

I have read many posts advising not to add the file directly to MySQL and to just store a reference, but I can't find a tutorial or instructions to guide how to store only a reference/path of the file in MySQL and access via PHP.

```
<?php 
     $file = 'BinarySearch.pdf';
     $filename = 'BinarySearch.pdf';
     header('Content-type: application/pdf');
     header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename = "' .$filename . '"');
     header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
     header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
     @readfile($file);
?>
```

The above code only opens the file directly stored on the server directly. I am not sure of how to store the path in MySQL. Then on my webpage I want to click a button to retrieve the file. (I have multiple files I want to store.) Thank you so much in advance but I can't find how to do this at all and its integral for my project.

Comment: Your code has no relation to your question. If you are storing the file path in a DB column then show us that code.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for having a look! The issue is I have tried many different bits online and now I don't have any code I can show. I only know what I want to achieve and really struggling with how to do it. Like, how to store the file reference and then how to retrieve it - I can't find anywhere online how to do this!

Comment: File reference is just a path to your file. You store it as any other text string in DB. See this Tutorial about PDO in PHP: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#dml

Answer (score 0):

Although the question isn't very clear, I'll take a stab at it with some assumptions.

I strongly discourage storing file as string in database as you've learned.

You have couple of options -

Use a cloud provider like Amazon S3 to push the pdf file to a bucket which returns a URL referencing that file. You then store that URL into your table as a reference as the API would return the link of the uploaded file. When you need to render the file when requested, simply locate the file via reference in your database and render it like you are currently doing. This will require more work as you need to setup your cloud provider account, provision a bucket (storage) and add SDK to your project to communicate with the storage engine.

Another approach would be that you designate a folder in your Web host that is accessible via your site url. For example - https://yourdomain.com/files/9d6fdb34-f92f-4078-9ab3-e5ada4522f2e.pdf

File (9d6fdb34-f92f-4078-9ab3-e5ada4522f2e.pdf) is physically stored in your cloud host local folder which can be any where like /var/files but your webserver points to this directory when user enter https://yourdomain.com/files/ and a reference to this file can be stored in a MySQL along with other metadata, example for your case -

```
file_guid :  9d6fdb34-f92f-4078-9ab3-e5ada4522f2e
file_name : BinarySearch
file_extension: pdf
user_id : 123 (if applicable)
```

In the user interface, your users see (BinarySearch.pdf) text which link to  https://yourdomain.com/files/9d6fdb34-f92f-4078-9ab3-e5ada4522f2e.pdf

When you store the file to the /var/files/ if your users are uploading files, always rewrite the file name as a unique uuid but store the file name they uploaded in your database as I specified above.

I hope this helps.

Good luck.

Comment: I'm really sorry the question wasn't clear - I am really new to programming hence not clear with my words. BUT a HUGE thank you for replying regardless, so I used the second approach you mentioned and it worked!! It does exactly what I needed it to do! I stored the file path http://192.167.90.2/SupportTools/BinarySearch.pdf in mysql- then used an SQL query to retrieve the file path and create a clickable link to view the PDF file!! Huge help, thank you so much - really had been trying literally since 7am!!

Comment: @NaiveLearner awesome! Very happy to hear that it worked for you. I'm also impressed by your ability to grasp and implement the solution quickly despite being new to programming. Nice work. 

One minor detail, I strongly suggest you not store the full file link in mysql. Instead of 192.167.90.2/SupportTools/BinarySearch.pdf just store /SupportTools/BinarySearch.pdf I say this because you could change machines in the future or you are currently in development and that 192.167.90.2 could change to something else in production.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense - I have changed the file path as you mentioned. Thank you ever so much, I'm really grateful!